# Дублирование значений ключей при добавлении новых записей

Tags: python, dict

Есть данные в dataframe pandas формата:

```
  ticker,price,size,time
  potato,2014,60,4057
  potato,2015,62,4073
  potato,2014,61,4076
```

Необходимо создать словарь, где ключами будут ticker и вложенный словарь с ключами size со значениями price, time и delta в виде списков. Для каждого значения size необходимо создавать не только один ключ, но и 2 дополнительных со значением +/-1, т.е. после первой итерации создается словарь potato с 3 ключами 60, 59 и 61 и так для каждой строки.
Обработка первой строки:

```
{potato:{60:{[4057],[2014],[0]},
         61:{[4057],[2014],[0]},
         59:{[4057],[2014].[0]}}
```

Проблема в том, что при 2 итерации, когда мы заносим значения в ключи 62, 61 и 63, при занесении значения списков в ключ 61 эти значения, также дублируются в ключах 60 и 59, как будто все 3 первоначально созданных ключа ссылаются на одну область памяти.
Получается так:

```
{potato:{60:{[4057,4073],[2014,2015],[0,16]},
         61:{[4057,4073],[2014,2015],[0,16]},
         59:{[4057,4073],[2014,2015],[0,16]},
         62:{[4073],[2015],[0]},
         63:{[4073],[2015],[0]}
```

А должно быть так:

```
{potato:{60:{[4057],[2014],[0]},
         61:{[4057,4073],[2014,2015],[0,16]},
         59:{[4057],[2014],[0]},
         62:{[4073],[2015],[0]},
         63:{[4073],[2015],[0]}
```

Подскажите, как написать код грамотно, чтобы такого не происходило.

Сам код:

```
import pandas as pd

def robodetect(zz):
    time = []
    price = []
    delta = []
    if zz.ticker not in robot_dict:
        time.append(zz.time)
        price.append(zz.price)
        delta.append(0)
        robot_dict[zz.ticker] = {zz.size: {"time": time, "price": price, "delta": delta},
                                 zz.size+1: {"time": time, "price": price, "delta": delta},
                                 zz.size-1: {"time": time, "price": price, "delta": delta}}
    else:
        for i in [0, 1, -1]:
            if zz.size+i in robot_dict[zz.ticker]:
                time = []
                price = []
                delta = []
                time = robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i]['time']
                time.append(zz.time)
                robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i]['time'] = time
                price = robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i]['price']
                price.append(zz.price)
                robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i]['price'] = price
                delta = robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i]['delta']
                e = time[-1] - time[-2]
                delta.append(e)
                robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i]['delta'] = delta
            else:
                time = []
                time.append(zz.time)
                price = []
                price.append(zz.price)
                delta = []
                delta.append(0)
                robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i] = {"time": time, "price": price, "delta": delta}

q1 = "d:\Python_Soft\\Temp\\data_potato.txt"
dfah=pd.read_csv(q1,delimiter=',')
robot_dict = {}
for row in dfah.itertuples(index=False):
    robodetect(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали в одном из Python чатов. Ларчик просто открывался:

```
def robodetect(zz):
    if zz.ticker not in robot_dict:
        robot_dict[zz.ticker] = {zz.size: {"time": [zz.time], "price": [zz.price], "delta": [0]},
                                 zz.size+1: {"time": [zz.time], "price": [zz.price], "delta": [0]},
                                 zz.size-1: {"time": [zz.time], "price": [zz.price], "delta": [0]}}
    else:
        for i in [0, 1, -1]:
            if zz.size+i in robot_dict[zz.ticker]:
                robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i]['time'].append(zz.time)
                robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size + i]['price'].append(zz.price)
                time = robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size + i]['time']
                e = time[-1] - time[-2]
                robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size + i]['delta'].append(e)
            else:
                robot_dict[zz.ticker][zz.size+i] = {"time": [zz.time], "price": [zz.price], "delta": [0]}
```